# Retrieving data from firebase returned nil

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the code I tried to test.

Tree:

```
{
  "WorkingTime" : {
    "CloseTime" : 20,
    "SpaceTime" : 30,
    "StartTime" : 7
  }
}
```

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        handel = ref.child("WorkingTime").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]{
                let startTimeFB = dict["StartTime"] as? String
                let endTimeFB = dict["CloseTime"] as? String
                print("\(startTimeFB ?? "nill") and \(endTimeFB ?? "nill")"
            }
        })
}
```

Apparently, it printed `nill and nill`

Comment: please add your database

Comment: @PeterHaddad I added

Comment: Try changing `dict["StartTime"] as? String` to `dict["StartTime"] as? Int`.

Comment: What did you get in the console?

Comment: @Kamran I tried and turned out it did retrieved perfectly, I should have test this first. Thanks

Comment: @Kamran also the problem is fixed when I change `String` to `Int`. Thank you a lot, I don't why I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key name and type cast seems to be the two problems. Please try the following code,

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        handel = ref.child("WorkingTime").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]{
                let startTimeFB = dict["StartTime"] as? Int
                let closeTimeFB = dict["CloseTime"] as? Int
                print("\(startTimeFB ?? 0) and \(closeTimeFB ?? 0)"
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Because the output was nil so I didn't notice it until I changed String to Int. Thanks, it worked